# access IDP intiated sign on from external server

Tags: c#, active-directory, webserver, saml-2.0, adfs

I have configured ADFS so a link like the following works fine from within the network.

https://adfs.[SERVER].com/adfs/ls/idpinitiatedsignon.htm

I am developing a C# application to be hosted on a different server and i need the above link to work from that server, which is outside of the ADFS server network.

I am looking for a way to open some sort of relay so i can access from anywhere (or at least from this one other server). Thanks for any help.

Comment: Sounds like you havent deployed any Web Application Proxy (WAP) role based server yet. The AD FS proxy functionality is made available with the Web Application Proxy role. This is how an external client accesses an internal AD FS deployment. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/deployment/deploying-federation-server-proxies-w2k12r2

Comment: @maweeras Thanks for the advice. I have now set up a proxy and ran into a different problem. After installing and configuring AD FS on the proxy and then restarting the server, the AD FS windows service will not start. The error is code 1064. Seems like something is wrong with the ADServiceAccount that the service is Logged in as. Any idea what could cause this issue?